# Pandas delete rows and update index

Tags: python, pandas

I've got data with two index columns (id, timestemp) and data columns (velocity). The data could look like this

```
Id timestemp velocity
0   0           0
0   1           0
0   2           0
1   1           1
1   2           1
1   3           0
1   4           1
1   5           1
2   4           1
2   5           1
2   6           1
```

My goal is now to remove all rows, where velocity is zero. Additionally, all timesteps should be consecutive. If there is a jump in the timesteps, the rows should be split up with a new id.

So after removing the rows with velocity = 0, the data look like this:

```
Id timestemp velocity
1   1           1
1   2           1
1   4           1
1   5           1
2   4           1
2   5           1
2   6           1
```

Now notice the jump in row (1,2) to (1,4). Therefore rows (1, 4) and rows (1,5) should get a new unique index (for instance: max index + 1). The data then looks like this:

```
Id timestemp velocity
1   1           1
1   2           1
2   4           1
2   5           1
2   6           1 
3   4           1
3   5           1
```

I've got some code for removing the rows:

```
df = df.drop(df[velocity == 0].index)
```

But I don't know how to assign rows a new unique index if there is a jump in the second index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with custom groups:

```
# which rows are velocity=0?
m = df['velocity'].eq(0)
# which timestamps are consecutive per id?
# make groups
g1 = df.groupby('Id')['timestemp'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
g2 = m.cumsum()

out = df[~m].assign(new_id=lambda d: d.groupby([g1, g2]).ngroup())
```

output:

```
    Id  timestemp  velocity  new_id
3    1          1         1       0
4    1          2         1       0
6    1          4         1       1
7    1          5         1       1
8    2          4         1       2
9    2          5         1       2
10   2          6         1       2
```

Comment: Is there also a way to directly work on the index (id, timestemp) or would you drop it before and reassign?
Ideally I would like new_id to replace id in the index.

Comment: Then I would do `df2 = df[~m] ; df2.index = df2.groupby([g1, g2]).ngroup()`. If MultiIndex, then better use columns and set (or craft a MultiIndex). You need to work with an external Series if you want to keep the date but use a period.